# React + Typescript Cannot find module './style.css' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

Estoy tiendo un problema al cargar un archivo css en mi aplicación react configurada desde cero utilizando `Typescript`. Ya he agregado varios paquetes para procesar los archivos css pero ninguna me quita el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi webpack config:

```
{
   test: /\.css$/i,
   use: [
   "style-loader",
    {
      loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader",
       options: {
         modules: true,
         namedExport: true,
         camelCase: true
       }
       },
       {
         loader: "css-loader",
         options: {
           importLoaders: 1,
           modules: true,
         }
       }
    ]
 }
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de darle muchas vueltas y con un poco de confusión con typescript. Para la configuración de webpack solo necesitaba `style-loader` y `css-loader`

Step 1: Paquetes necesarios

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true
      }
    }
  ],
},
```

Step 2: Eliminar error anteriormente redactado

Crear archivo `declaration.d.ts` dentro de la carpeta `./src` con el siguiente contenido:

```
declare module '*.css'
```

Eso debería quitar el error y podremos importar nuestro archivo css.

```
import styled from './index.css';
```